# What is the java type equivalent for the oracle datatype raw?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-4

In my oracle database table there is a `column` of datatype `raw`. Now in my `spring` bean class I want to map this table. So what java `datatype` is the equivalent of the oracle `raw` datatype ?

Comment: I woud go for byte[]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the following link, it should be mapped to `java.sql.Types.BINARY` or `java.sql.Types.VARBINARY` for the JDBC type, and `byte[]` for the Java type   :

[Oracle Datatype Mappings](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/a83724/basic3.htm)

Comment: so then how to we declare byte? the following is not working             byte test = 864182A09C1E47AE95E11431542C2133;